# pandas: How to find the max n values for each category in a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a huge municipal library catalog dataset with book title, the library it's in, the library's borough, and the number of times it was loaned out.

I want to find the top 3 most loaned books for each neighbourhood.

Ideally, I'd get something like this:

```
Borough    Title    Total_loans
A          Book1    35615 
A          Book2    34895
A          Book3    2548
B          Book1    6541
B          Book2    5425
```

etc.

This is the closest I was able to get, but the resulting data frame is not grouped by borough and hard to read.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"borough":["A", "B", "B", "A", "A"], "title":["Book2", "Book1", "Book2", "Book2", "Book1"], "total_loans":[4, 48, 46, 78, 15]})

top_boroughs = df.groupby(['borough','title'])
top_boroughs.aggregate(sum).sort(['total_loans','title'], ascending=False)
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In short:

```
df.groupby(level=[0,1]).sum().reset_index().sort_values(['borough', 'total_loans'], ascending=[1,0]).groupby('borough').head(3)
```

The steps:

- Do the correct grouping and sum
- Sort by borough and maximum values
- group by borough and take `3` first

This is superior to the accepted answer due to both

- readability (yes, one long line, but you could equally split it up): all standard operations
- performance (standard optimized operations compared to enlarging a dataframe iteratively with `concat`, wasting memory

My output (using `head(1)` since test data has only `2` rows per group:

```
Out[484]: 
  borough  title  total_loans
1       A  Book2           82
2       B  Book1           48
```

Comment: Thank you for providing a better answer. I accepted this one instead.

Comment: Trying this this solution on another dataset, I get en error saying that level > 0 requires MultiIndex. Did you skip a step before groupby with level?

Comment: @robroc I don't remember what I did a year ago, but yes, using `level > 0` requires MultiIndex. I guess the first step should be `df.set_index(['borough', 'title'], inplace=true)`

Comment: The sort method has been deprecated. The warning mentions sort_values as a replacement.

Answer (score 2):

something like this:

```
t = df.groupby(['borough', 'title']).sum()
t.sort('total_loans', ascending=True)
t = t.groupby(level=[0,1]).head(3).reset_index()
t.sort(['borough', 'title'], ascending=(True, False)) #not sure if this is necessary, tough to tell with limited data, but just in case...
```

Comment: you could easily chain all these together, i just broke it up for moderate readability

Comment: @acushner Hehe I just noticed that we are converging to the same thing.  Yours is cleaner, but I think you need the sort() before the head().

Comment: I get a strange error on the second line: `ValueError: cannot insert title, already exists`

Answer (score 0):

```
'''
Created on Jul 30, 2014

class TopX():



    def __init__(self, top,sortFunction):
        self.topX=top
        self.sortFunction=sortFunction
        self.data=[]


    def addNewItem(self,item):
        self.data.append(item)
        self.data.sort( key=self.sortFunction,reverse=True)
        self.data=self.data[:self.topX]
    def getMax(self):
        return self.data



def runMe():
    top = TopX(3, lambda x:int(x[2]))
    with open("lib.txt","r") as f:
        string= f.readlines()
        for line in string:
            data= [x.strip() for x in line.split(' ')]
            top.addNewItem(data)

    print top.getMax()    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    runMe()
```

Works with input file in format:

```
A Book1 1
A Book2 10
A Book3 3
B Book1 7
B Book2 5
```

Giving results:

```
[['A', 'Book2', '10'], ['B', 'Book1', '7'], ['B', 'Book2', '5']]
```

You may specify amount of top books and sorting key if you need to adjust criteria later on.